# I'm changing my code but the compiled program isn't being affected

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I'm doing a project in C++ with Codeblocks. I closed out of Codeblocks and re-opened it, and now when I edit, save and compile the code the .exe doesn't change at all. The log says "Checking for existence: C:\Users\AJ\Code\sndbrd\bin\Debug\sndbrd.exe
Executing: `"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\AJ\Code\sndbrd\bin\Debug\sndbrd.exe"`  (in `C:\Users\AJ\Code\sndbrd\.`)"
Also I have two executables, `main.exe`, located where `main.cpp` is, and `sndbrd` in the **`bin/debug`** folder.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler uses timestamp of  obj executable/obj-files/cpp-header files to determine if compilation/linking is necessary. 
If for whatever reason your executable/obj-files  timestamps >  cpp-header files, (ie. cpp-header is newer) then compiler wont think compilation/linking is necessary.

Simple solution is to simply delete all the obj/exe files and then recompile.

It should work.